# Can't call new page by controller in Asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to call new page by click on a button by `jQuery` from `Index.cshtml` :

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function(){
        var idser = $("#Name").val();

        $.ajax({    
           type: "POST",
           url: "/User/getAll",
           id : idser,
           success: function() {
               alert("success");
           }
       });
    }); 
});
```

It call to my controller action : `UserController/getAll`

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public ActionResult getAll(string id,string name)
{
    return View("AllUser"); 
}
```

But is still at `Index.cshtml` not go to `AllUser.cshtml` page? I don't know why...please help.
UPDATE :
my jquery function call my action in controller , and the action work correctly but it not return to AllUser.cshtml page.

Comment: The whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the **same** page, and ajax calls never redirect to another page. Do not use ajax if you wanting to navigate to your `getAll()` method

Comment: use return RedirectToAction("NameAction"); in Controller

Answer (score 0):

Updating in response to clarification in comments:

In the `success` callback,

```
location.href="/user/getall";
```

That will cause the browser to navigate to that URL after the ajax post has completed.

---

A button that posts a value from an input to another page - that's a form.

```
<form action="/User/getAll">
    <input type="submit" value="Click me">
</form>
```

I don't know where your id is coming from, but you can put a hidden input in the form and a script to populate it (unless it's a user input - then you can just put the input right in the form.)

```
<form action="/User/getAll">
    <input type="submit" value="Click me">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="hiddenId"/>
</form>

<script>
    $("#hiddenId").val($("#Name").val());
</script>
```

Or, if you want to be sure that your form's `action` URL matches your route:

```
<form action='@Url.Action("getAll", "User")'>
```

(Assuming that the controller is called "User".)

Comment: I want call it by jQuery and from controller : UserController.cs , action getAll will direct to AllUser.cshtml, I dont want go by a form, can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). I would attempt using a tag-helper in the `Ajax` setup like this:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function(){
        var idser = $("#Name").val();

        $.ajax({    
           type: "POST",
           url: '@Url.Action("User", "getAll", new { id = "ID", name = "searchName" })',
           id : idser,
           success: function() {
               alert("success");
           }
       });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't know what is your purpose behind using ajax while your are redirecting the other page ?
But you if still want to use Ajax, you can achieve this by two ways:
1) you can assign `window.location` in your success block.

2) Use your code by following way :

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function(){
        var idser = $("#Name").val();

        $.ajax({    
           type: "GET",
           url: "/User/getAll",
           id : idser,
           success: function() {
               alert("success");
               return true;
           }
       });
    }); 
});
```

you can try it by putting `return true` in your script.

hope it helps to you

Comment: I want use MVC model so I use Ajax to call a action in controller and from this controller it will call the next view.

Comment: It is a demo function I try to pass parameter form a view to controller and direct to another view from controller

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

window.location.href = "yourUrl" can help you.

```
 $("#btnSearch").click(function(){
            var idser = $("#Name").val();

            $.ajax({    
               type: "POST",
               url: "/User/getAll",
               id : idser,
               success: function() {
                   alert("success");
                  window.location.href ="../yourUrl";  //This is working!
               }
           });
        }); 
    });
```

You may redirect in Controller this like:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public ActionResult getAll(string id,string name)
{
    return RedirectToAction("NameOfAction"); //Here is going Name of Action       wich returns View AllUser.cshtml

}
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: can I call new url after function done in controller ?

Comment: @moviehay0032 You should use  this like in Controller : return RedirectToAction("NameAction");